# cgi and tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cgi

im trying to run a cgi script (.cgi) with tomcat. I am getting the below error and cant find out whats wrong. I know i should really use apache and mod proxy but this really isnt my area of expertise so im taking the easy way out!

Thanks for any help.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "perl" (in directory "C:\Java\tomcat\webapps\my_app_name\WEB-INF\cgi"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
    java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet$CGIRunner.run(CGIServlet.java:1705)
    org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet.doGet(CGIServlet.java:597)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:416)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something of a guess, but you might need to add the following to your `web.xml` file so that Tomcat can find the perl executable.  Tomcat doesn't look in your `PATH` to find executables, apparently:

```
executable
C:\perl\bin\perl
```

Use the actual path to perl on your system, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the "executable" parameter in the servlet element.  According to the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html), the default is "perl", which is probably what is triggering your error.  Maybe changing it to something like cmd.exe will work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that the executable named `perl` cannot be found.  Is perl installed on your system?  Is it in the path?

Answer (score 0):

No perl is not installed. The CGI script is actually c++. I haven't installed anything other than the default tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i didnt find out what was the correct syntax to run C++ cgi scripts, but if you leave the param blank it will run any script type.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>executable</param-name>
  <param-value></param-value>
</init-param>
```